# How to get which integer is in a certain position in a set?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, set, binary-search-tree

Given a set of integers, how can I know which integer is in a certain position, if the elements of a set were ordered in an increasing way? For example, given a set of integers how can I obtain the smaller integer or the second smaller integer etc

Is it possible to do this in logarithmic time? I mean, I know there are obvious ways of doing what I asked, but is there any that works in logarithmic time?

Comment: In a ordered set you should be able to do that in constant time O(1). The smallest integer is at S[0] and the second smallest is at S[1] or am I missing something?

Comment: You might be shocked at how fast vector can be for ints. Something like $v.insert(std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), new_val), new_val);$ as your insert function and then just $v[k]$ to find out the value in place k. The insert does require copying all of the data after the insertion point, but finding that point is log(n) time, and often the copy is one CPU instruction, though maybe several cycles. Try it, benchmark it, and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of an `std::set` *are* stored in increasing order.

No, you can't find the item at position N in logarithmic time though--it requires linear time.

```
auto start = your_set.begin();
std::advance(start, N);
```

In theory it *could* be done in logarithmic time by having each node of the tree store a count of the nodes to its left (i.e., preceding it in order), but `std::set` doesn't require that or provide a (standardized) interface to use it even if it were present.

Comment: And is it possible to do in logarithmic time using std::multiset?

Comment: Yes, std::multiset works the same way, except that it can hold duplicate values. As long as it is sorted in increasing order, you can query in logarithmic time. But, in what case would you want to use a multiset?

Comment: Basically, I would like to find the item at position N in logarithmic time. I can't use an array because throughout my program the user will remove and insert items and ordering the elements after that would be too inefficient. Also I don't want to implement my own AVL-Tree or Red-Black Tree, simply because I would like to know how to solve this kind of problems in a more standardized way, making use of STL library, so that writing the code won't be so time consuming.

Comment: @Francisco: the standard library doesn't provide a data structure that's really well suited to this particular task. As I said in the answer, to do what you want, each node needs to store a count of the nodes to its left (and you need to update that count as you add/delete nodes). The standard library just doesn't have anything that does that, so if you want it, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: This is a missing container in `std`: the fast index sorted tree.  Total children, or total left children, both work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your elements were sorted ("ordered in an increasing way"), then there is a way to search for an arbitrary integer in logarithmic time. Use binary search trees. Obviously, if you want the best possible time span, you will want to use self-balancing trees (such as red-black trees, avl trees, ...). I believe that the C++ options for this are part of `std::set`.

However, I'm not really sure what you mean by "obtain the smaller integer." If you mean, given a set of integers, find the minimum element, then you will want to look up Heaps. Heaps do the job better than trees, because in the case of Heaps, querying the minimum value will happen in constant time, while insertions and deletions happen in logarithmic time. I believe the C++ options for this are part of `std::priority_queue`.

Alternatively, if you wanted the fastest way of searching for integers, you can use hash tables, since they allow querying in expected constant time, with constant time insertion. The C++ options for this are `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: what I meant was, given a set of integers, is it possible to find the element at position N in logarithmic time?(without implementing my own AVL Trees or Red-Black trees)